# Maximize Profit Under Time Limitations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am preparing for the ACTM State Contest, and I stumbled across this tie-breaker problem. I have no idea how to do it, so can anyone help me out?

A small company manufactures two styles of chairs, the deluxe and the standard. The profit on each style is $40 and $25, respectively. The company has an assembly and finishing room with 250 and 150 hours available, respectively. The deluxe takes 3 hours in the assembly room and 2 hours in the finishing room. The standard takes 2 hours in the assembly room and 1 hour in the finishing room.

In order to maximize profit, how many chairs of each style should the company manufacture each week?

a) Write the objective function
b) Solve the problem

Comment: Look up the Simplex Algorithm. Maximize profit subject to the  fishing room and assembly room constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Number of chairs per week: 
$$
x = (x_d, x_s)^\top
$$
Objective function: 
$$
c^\top x
$$
with 
$$
c = (40, 25)^\top
$$
Constraints
$$
A x \le b
$$
with
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
b =
\begin{pmatrix}
250 \\
150 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Linear integer program:
$$
\max \{ c^\top x \mid Ax \le b, x \ge 0, x \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \}
$$